# why's optionsMenu show in two line

Tags: android, android-optionsmenu

I don't know why my title show a bank line.
Now i want to show only optionMenu.
Please help me.
[image]

Here id my code
Manifest

```
enter code here
<activity
        android:name=".FileWalker"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar"
        android:uiOptions="none" />
    <activity
```

on activity

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);
    // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }


@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreateOptionsMenu");
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.files, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

which type style apply in manifest file i don't know but you use this style +14 API

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar" >
```

Comment: :( it's the same
i don't know what's the first line

Comment: please try to remove ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    }

Comment: please onCreateOptionsMenu not write in OnCreate method